# Dynamic Routes Nex.js

Tags: javascript, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm trying to create a dynamic route for messages based on the `senderId`, but I don't seem to be doing it correctly, this API is simply returning all messages from the database, instead of only returning messages from a specific `senderId (http://localhost:3000/api/messages?senderId=29)`. I'm using Next.js 13 with the App Route directory. This is the dynamic route that I created `api/messages/[messageId]/route.ts` in this case the api to retrieve my messages through `senderId` is present inside `[messageId]` . Below is my API and my model

```
model Message {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  senderId  Int
  content   String
  imageUrl  String?
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  sender    User     @relation(fields: [senderId], references: [id])
}
```

```
import { db as prisma } from "@/lib/db";

export async function GET(
  request: Request,
  context: { params: { senderId: number } }
) {
  try {
    const senderId = Number(context.params.senderId);

    const userMessages = await prisma.message.findMany({
      where: {
        senderId: {
          equals: senderId,
        },
      },
    });

    if (!userMessages || userMessages.length === 0) {
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ message: "Mensagens não encontradas" }),
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(userMessages), { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erro ao buscar mensagens:", error);
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ message: "Erro ao buscar mensagens" }),
      {
        status: 500,
      }
    );
  } finally {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  }
}
```

I replicated what the doc said, but it was unsuccessful